# defining UI component's height as percentage(or relative) to screen height

Tags: android

Need some help with a UI problem in android. I am trying to create an activity where a text view is supposed to fill all the space above the two buttons on the bottom right and bottom left.
[image: layout]

I don't want to hardcode any height/width parameters but want to define them as %. So I want button height to be 10% of the screen height and the textview to be 90% of the screenheight.

Hence I keep button width as Wrap_text and the textview width as fill_parent.

Below is the xml file as I have it as of now. The problem is in defining the height. How do i specify button height as 10% of screenheight and/or textview height as 90% of screen height?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activityclass" >

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_above="@+id/button1" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
 android:text="<-prev" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button2"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
 android:text="next->" />
```

Any help will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `LinearLayout` then you can use the `layout_weight` attribute to make the `TextView` fill the available height left:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Activityclass" >

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1" />

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
 android:text="<-prev" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button2"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
 android:text="next->" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When views have the `layout_weight` attribute the system first calculates the dimensions of the views without the attribute, then splits up the remaining space between those that do. Each view with a layout weight gets a `layout_weight/sum(all layout_weights)` fraction of the remaining space.

Comment: i tried this. The relativelayout takes 100% of screen height thus hiding the textview.

Comment: No, the `RelativeLayout` wraps the content inside. If it is filling the whole screen make sure you don't have one of the button heights set to `fill_parent`. Copy-and-pasting the above layout works, I have tested it.

Comment: you are right. I had forgot to take out the "android:layout_alignParentBottom" parameter in Button and hence the issue. So it works now. But I am not sure if one of my original question has got answered. The height of button here will be "wrap_content". Hence how can I be sure that it is a percentage(say 20%) of total screen height. The reason I need to know the exact percentage is because in my code I am using that percentage to find out how much text can fit inside textview.

Answer (score 1):

With `layout_weight` you can specify a size ratio between multiple views.

E.g. you have a MapView and a table which should show some additional information to the map.

The map should use **3/4 of the screen** and **table should use 1/4 of the screen**.

Then you will set the `layout_weight` of the `map to 3` and the `layout_weight of the table to 1.

To get it work you also have to set the `height or width (depending on your orientation) to 0px.`